# getting system time without using any built in classes

Tags: java

How can I get the system time without using any built in classes in Java?

Please provide some hints.

Comment: you have to write your own implementation :P

Comment: sounds tricky since you can't do *anything* useful without using at least one built-in class in Java.

Comment: `select SYSDATE from dual;` You're from Oracle, they do it that way.

Answer (score 3):

Impossible. You should use `System` class and it's static methods or other classes. Otherwise you can access OS dependent native code, but this will require to use built in classes for `JNI`.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't everything in Java extend `Object`?

Isn't `Object` a built-in class?

Therefore, you cannot achieve what you want.

(an argumentative answer, but proves a point)